# How to transfer the residuals to the uniform margin for copula-GARCH model in R?

Tags: r, garch, copula, pit

I am studying the copula model in finance. To the best of my knowledge, I need to fit the GARCH model to my data (to each time series). Then, I need to get the residuals for each. After that, I need to transfer the residuals to uniform margins to fit the copula model. My question is, how to do the latter step using IFM by Joe, in R?
I found a code where the author used `pobs` function to find the pseudo-observation. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/vignettes/copula_GARCH.html) . However, in some papers, the authors used IFM of joe. To the best of my knowledge, IFM is different from `pobs` function.

**Edit based on the comment of @RichardHardy (thanks a lot)**

To the best of my understanding, the following code used to estimate the margins distribution (if not should I estimate the margins of residulas?):

`uspec <- ugarchspec(varModel, mean.model = meanModel, distribution.model = "std") fit <- apply(X., 2, function(x) ugarchfit(uspec, data = x))`

Then, I can check the standardized of margins and transfer them to copula using the following code:

`Z. <- sapply(fit, residuals, standardize = TRUE)`

`U. <- pobs(Z.)`.

So, to use `IFM` method of Joe, I can use `U. <- pt(Z.)` to transfer the standardized residuals to copula data. Is that correct?

Comment: You got the question (as you phrased it), you got the answer (use `pobs`), what else is unclear to you?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks. But, I found that some paper use IFM method which it is different from `pobs` function. That what makes me confused.

Comment: How does IFM differ from the method you have described? And what is your question?

Comment: `pobs` function estimates the margins and copula parameters non-parametrically. While the IFM estimates the margin parameters (parametrically) at the first step, then the copula parameters (non-parametrically) at the second step. My question is how to use IFM for the residuals after fitting the GARCH model.

Comment: If the only problem were finding the parametric equivalent of the nonparametric `pobs`, then one should use `pnorm` when the standardized residuals are assumed to be standard normal and other quantile functions starting with `p` that match the assumed distribution of the standardized residuals in case the distribution is different from normal.

Comment: Excellent. I do not know how to thank you. I think I learned a new point, here.  For example, the `std` used in the following code `uspec <- ugarchspec(varModel, mean.model = meanModel, distribution.model = "std")` is the possible estimation of the margins. Then,  I can use `pt` instead of `pobs`. Is that correct? I will update my question.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks a lot. It is really amazing (upvote + accept the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only problem were finding the parametric equivalent of the nonparametric `pobs`, then one should use `pnorm` when the standardized residuals are assumed to be standard normal and other quantile functions starting with `p` that match the assumed distribution of the standardized residuals in case the distribution is different from normal.

> I can use pt instead of pobs. Is that correct?

`pt` yields an unstandardized Student-$t$ distribution, and its standard deviation may not be 1. The standardized residuals from a GARCH model will always have a standard deviation of 1, so it will be a scaled Student-$t$ distribution. Luckily, there is the `pit` function from the `rugarch` package that (when applied on an object of the `uGARCHfit` class) selects the appropriate distribution automatically and does the probability integral transform for you.